# Changing directory permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions

I need to get write permissions to the lib directory of my application (i.e. `/data/data/com.my.app/lib/`) and store a file there, and I need to do it from my application. Is it possible? and if so, how?

*EDIT*

By my application I mean using Java. `/data/data/com.my.app/lib/` is the path to the `lib` directory of the same application.

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, as LeffelMania said, I couldn't find any convenient way to do it. Fortunately, we solved this problem in a better way - we convinced the developers of the library to make it more dynamic :). Thanks again LeffelMania.

Comment: What are you writing? Store it as a byte array in the DB...

Comment: I am writing an SO which is later loaded to my program. I can store it in other directories, such as `/data/data/com.my.app/` and `/data/data/com.my.app/files/` but I need it to specifically be saved in the `bin` directory.

Comment: You need to tell us why it has to be in the bin directory, as there's no logical explanation for that. Only your application's executable binaries should be in the bin directory.

Comment: I don't think it's relevant at all, but let's say I can't control the library and it checks if located in bin or another folder. It doesn't matter though, see edited question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to directly write into another app's file space. Your app has write access to its own space and external storage (SD card) with permission.

However, I can imagine a couple ways to do this, depending on what you're trying to do, specifically.

1) Write the file to the SD card from one app. Have the other check if it's there and read from it when it opens. Make sure to write it to your own proprietary folder - don't clog the user's storage space. If applicable to your situation, delete the file and your folders on the SD card from the other app once you've read the file.

2) Register a custom BroadcastReceiver in the recipient app, and stick the data you need to transfer inside of an Intent that you will send from the other app. You should use your own action String so that no other application in the system attempts to use your Broadcast.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not another application, but my application. and I can write to other directories under `/data/data/com.my.app/`